# What does $\int_\mathbb{R^d}$ means in terms of limits

Tags: probability, limits, area

This might be a silly question, but please help me understand that does the limits of the following expression. The left-hand-side is the actual expression, while the right-hand-side is my understanding.

$$\displaystyle \large e^{-\lambda\int_\mathbb{R^d}(1-e^{-f(x)})dx} = e^{-\lambda\int_x^\infty(1-e^{-f(x)})dx}$$

(We are dealing with a 2D euclidean plane here.)

Comment: the equation you wrote is complete nonsense, does not contain a limit, and I feel like includes the exponential unnecessarily.

Comment: This the equation of Laplace Functional of Poisson Point Process. It can be easily found with simple search over web

Comment: the equation you wrote is complete nonsense

Comment: You are misunderstanding what the left-hand side means. In the case of 2D (i.e., $d = 2$), $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(1-e^{-f(\mathrm{x})})\,\mathrm{dx} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1-e^{-f(x,y)})\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y $$ for any $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and likewise for other values of $d$'s. In particular, it less makes sense to convert this to a one-dimensional integral.

Comment: $\int_x^{\infty} ...dx$ never make sense.

Comment: oh ok. thanks for the comments and new info everyone. I appreciate it.